# Twitter API is not respecting my callback_url parameter

Tags: oauth, twitter, twitter-oauth, twython

I've read all the threads about simiular issues on SO and elsewhere, and none of them have solved my problem.

I'm using Twython as a wrapper around the API.  I've tried setting oauth_callback EVERYWHERE.  Using the internal mechanism in Tython (which is done by setting callback_url on instantiation), by manually modifying the auth_url and appending the argument by before redirecting the user, etc.  I've tried deleting and recreating both new twitter apps and new twitter accounts, to no avail.

Whenever I redirect the client to twitter, the correct oauth_callback is ALWAYS visible in the url along with the oauth_token, but the api always ignores this argument and overrides it with the url in the settings of my twitter app (both are under the same domain).  I have tried figuring this out for several hours and I'm at a dead end.  I've seen this work before and I've done it plenty of times, so I don't know what could possible be going wrong.

It's strange-- even if i set the callback to 'oob', which ought to trigger the PIN workflow rather than a callback, this argument is EVEN THEN ignored.  Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You specify the `oauth_callback` value when you get a request token as specified in OAuth 1.0a. In 1.0 it you could pass it along with with the user when they go to twitter.com but was changed for security reasons. You can read more about it in the [/oauth/request_token docs](https://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth#request-token).

Comment: I am using an updated version of Twython for authentication.  The object is instantiated with callback_url = {myURL}, and as far as I can tell, the library is handling everything properly.  https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython/blob/master/twython/twython.py

Comment: I don't know enough Python to know if twython is implementing `oauth_callback` properly but [this line](https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython/blob/master/twython/twython.py#L219) reads to me like it doesn't support OAuth 1.0a callbacks. I can confirm 100% that Twitter does support dynamic callbacks and if it isn't working either the lib doesn't support it or you are not calling the lib correctly.

Comment: ahhh good point, dont know how i missed that.  thats exactly what i needed to know.  thanks.